# Series about people living in two realities, being called by numbers in one

Tags: story-identification, tv

It begins with a main character waking up in a sugary, pink-tinted town in a middle of a desert, where every inhabitant is named by a number. It is later revealed that all characters also simultaneously live in a parallel, normal reality, while the town is actually a dream of one of the characters and a psycho-sociological experiment.

It was a single-season series, probably from 2005-2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like the 2009 remake of [The Prisoner](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1043714/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3).   It hits all the plot points you describe.  In the Village, everyone has a number, it in a desert, the houses are pink, and it is eventually revealed to only exist as a shared dream world.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the trailer as it shows the pink houses in the desert.

Comment: Whoa. Iron Maiden reference? Iron Maiden reference! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Tb8Jo11uGo

Comment: @jo1storm Not sure if that's tongue in cheek, but you do realise the Iron Maiden reference is to the original TV series?

Comment: @Mohirl of course I do. I just like the song and rarely have the chance to reference it :)

Comment: @jo1storm Sorry. You never know these days!

Comment: Precisely this! Thank you so much, it was bothering me for quite some time.